# CoffeeScript and sbt-concat

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, sbt

I'm having trouble concatenating and fingerprinting all the CoffeeScript files in Play application. Everything works fine for JavaScript files with `build.sbt` like this one

```
pipelineStages := Seq(concat, digest)

Concat.groups := Seq(
  "javascripts/app.js" -> group(((sourceDirectory in Assets).value / "javascripts") * "*.js")
)
```

But when `sourceDirectory` is changed to `resourcesManaged` that supposedly contains compiled CoffeeScript files `sbt-concat` doesn't pick them up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sbt-coffeescript, and all other official source task plugins, don't put their files in `resourcesManaged in Assets`, but instead their own sub-directory in `target/web/<taskname>`. They scope the `resourcesManaged` setting to their main task, in this case this means `resourcesManaged in (Assets, coffeescript)` and `resourcesManaged in (TestAssets, coffeescript)`.

When you run `sbt coffeescript` you can see the files are output to `target/web/coffeescript/main`. You can verify this by running `show web-assets:coffeescript::resourceManaged` from the sbt console.

Comment: Thanks. It turned out that the problem was with path separators. I was developing on Windows box and with Scala it's not at first apparent that it's a bad idea.